# copy file from GCS to Google Drive through Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I would like to instantiate a task (through airflow) which copy file in a bucket on google cloud storage to a drive.

I use the dedicated operator which is located in :

```
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_gdrive_operator import GcsToGDriveOperator
```

then the operator :

```
copy_files = GcsToGDriveOperator(
        task_id="copy_files",
        source_bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
        source_object='{}/{}/forecasted/*'.format(COUNTRY_TRIGRAM, PRED_START_RANGE),
        destination_object="content/drive/Shared Drives/FORECAST_TEST",
        gcp_conn_id="airflow_service_account_conn_w_drive"
    )
```

The task is succesfull but do not copy the file in the "destination object" which is the part that i'm not sure what to put in.

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing Airflow [GcsToGDriveOperator](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/gcs_to_gdrive_operator.html) source code , I assume Airflow leverages [*gcs_hook.download()*](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcs_hook.html) method downloading the files from GCS and [*gdrive_hook.upload_file()*](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/gdrive_hook.html#GoogleDriveHook) uploading these objects to the target Gdrive location.

Given said above, `gcs_hook.download()` method records each action for the successful operation result:

```
self.log.info('File downloaded to %s', filename)
```

Similarly, `gdrive_hook.upload_file()` writes each file uploading iteration as a logging message:

```
self.log.info("File %s uploaded to gdrive://%s.", local_location, remote_location)
```

Even though the task succeeded, I believe that you can capture the above mentioned events in Airflow [logs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/logs) within the particular task, looking for the actual source and destination location paths derived from `GcsToGDriveOperator()` definition.

You can consider even Airflow workers log inspection connecting to GKE cluster and launching `kubectl` command-line tool:

```
kubectl logs deployment/airflow-worker -n $(kubectl get ns| grep composer*| awk '{print $1}') -c airflow-worker | grep 'Executing copy'
```

Comment: I can track airflow's logs which said that my file "/tmp/tmpwj__bkqs " has been upload to gdrive:// > "content/drive/Shared Drives/FORECAST_TEST"/000000. that indeed the path I specified in the destination object. But my issue is not to track where's my file but to send the file in the good location so to specified the right path, I don't find my copied file where I would like to find him that mean I don't specify the path in the proper way so I looking for the right "syntax" way to specify it

Comment: This [thread](https://www.highviewapps.com/kb/what-should-i-enter-in-the-file-path-when-using-google-drive-as-the-destination-for-my-exported-files/) might be relevant for you. Does this help you to get proper path syntax?

Comment: According to this thread I think my path is properly defined but It still did not work, I think the GcsToGDriveOperator points to the airflow drive instead of my airflow local but I didnt found any argument that said "this is my drive"

Comment: `GcsToGDriveOperator` is actually used to obtain files from GCS bucket but not the local drive.

Comment: Oh I see .. so I took the wrong path did you know another way to transfer to a local drive ? thanks

Comment: To make it less confusing, can you elaborate exactly what do you want to perform. Where is you source object located and where you want to copy it?

Comment: my object is located in GCS (the bucket of the project) and I want to transfert it to a local shared Drive in google drive

Comment: Obviously `GcsToGDriveOperator` is exactly what you need. You can check in this [article](https://medium.com/@philipplies/transferring-data-from-google-drive-to-google-cloud-storage-using-google-colab-96e088a8c041) how the Gdrive path can be correctly retained in `gsutil` GCP cloud command-line tool for the reference.